# How to create 2 connected environments with different parents?

Tags: r

`.BaseNamespaceEnv` and `baseenv()` behave like this, they have different parents but changing/adding a binding in one updates the other too.

Can I emulate this ?

I expect something like this after we define the function `semi_clone()` :

```
e1 <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
e2 <- semi_clone(e1, parent = .GlobalEnv)
parent.env(e2)
#> .GlobalEnv
e2$x <- 1
e1$x
#> [1] 1
```

**Use case**

To answer comments, hopefully it does not confuse further!

2 functions have different parents and ancestors, but I want them to have connected masks, so a value changed in one is changed in the other.

```
mask1 <- list2env(list(x = 1, y = 2))
mask2 <- mask1 # in use case it wouldn't be the same

# contain self for easy update
mask1$mask <- mask1

# in use case, in environment parent1
add <- function() {
  mask$x <- sample(5, 1)
  x + y
}

# in use case, in environment parent2
multiply <- function() {
  x * y
}

# stitch a mask between their environment and their parent
environment(add) <- mask1
environment(multiply) <- mask2

set.seed(2)
multiply()
#> [1] 2
add()
#> [1] 7
multiply()
#> [1] 10
```

Comment: I don't know how base R is doing that with `baseenv()`, but it seems like you'd need to define a trigger of sorts that, when something is changed in one, a udf is fired. Is that a safe interpretation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is there a critical use case where the  more common heirarchical set of environments won't do what you need?

Comment: Does this help?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050094/assign-values-to-part-of-an-object-in-another-environment-in-r     or   Hadley's   http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: The base namespace is a special case and handled differently by R. Its parent is always the global environment, and this ensures that packages will look in the base namespace for symbols before looking for them in attached packages. However, it also hoists itself to the top of the search path (just before the empty env) so that interactive code works from within the global environment. The way it does this is written into the guts of the R language and can't be easily replicated in R code.

Comment: But its certainly possible to write a class that behaves this way. My guess is that for efficiency, shallow copying with parent-switching on the fly might be a better route than duplication of environments with write-copy triggers, (@r2evans I think this is what you are suggesting?)

Comment: @AllanCameron I agree, a class-wrapper might be more easily implemented, I wouldn't even know where to begin with write-copy triggers.

Comment: A use case would be to share a data mask between 2 functions that have different parents and that are able to modify the mask themselves. I think classes won't help here

Comment: I think if we just modify objects and not create some, we can have active bindings in both environment (both for get and set), that would map to a third environment under the empty env, containing the values.

Comment: I'm struggling to get my head around the use case. Are you able to provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @AllanCameron  Hey, i already asked that!   :-)

Comment: Documentation states "The object .BaseNamespaceEnv is the namespace environment for the base package. The environment of the base package itself is available as baseenv()."  Hadley describes how a package (in this case base) has a namespace environment and package environment. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#namespaces and there states "Every binding in the package environment is also found in the namespace environment."  But these environments are locked, right?.  So I don't understand your assertion that "changing/adding a binding to one updates the other."